# How to show the git HEAD hash in bash?

Tags: bash, git, shell

I was able to show my current branch in my bash (see photo below) by following the instructions from [How do I show the git branch with colours in Bash prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/730754/how-do-i-show-the-git-branch-with-colours-in-bash-prompt).

[image]

But I would like to ask if its possible we can append the git HEAD hash beside of the branch?

```
// format
user@user: directory(CURRENT_BRANCH)(CURRENT_HEAD_HASH)

// looks like
user@user: directory(feature/user_profile_page_be)(2d00c77)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
parse_rev_parse() {
 git rev-parse --short HEAD 2>/dev/null
}
```

the above change (`2>/dev/null`) suppresses errors when you're in a folder that is not a git repo.
otherwise, on every command in Terminal, you'll get this message:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

this is similar to the other function (`parse_git_branch`).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to show the hash and changed the color. Check [here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-shell-change-the-color-of-my-shell-prompt-under-linux-or-unix/)  for color reference

```
force_color_prompt=yes
color_prompt=yes
parse_git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}
parse_rev_parse() {
 git rev-parse --short HEAD
}
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
 PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[01;31m\]$(parse_git_branch)\033[01;32m\]($(parse_rev_parse))\[\033[00m\]\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

[image]